# Access outer scope from within instance created with new

Tags: javascript

I have read dozens of articles and posts today about closures and scopes in JavaScript today and still do not get why I cannot access Socket from within CoreClass and how I get there:

```
CoreClass = function() {
    console.log('CoreClassLocalisation', Localisation) // works??
    console.log('CoreClassSocket', Socket) // undefined, hell why, its even closer?
}

var Localisation = 'im a localisation'

Request = function() {
    var Socket = 'im a socket'
    new CoreClass()
}

new Request
```

Comment: it exists only in `Request` scope because you define it `var Socket` inside that function. Instead, you define `Localisation` in the outer scope, which can be accessed by the inner scope of `CoreClass`

Comment: I can see your confusion, because if you defined an object inline (instead of instantiating `CoreClass`) then `Socket` would be in scope. But from where the `CoreClass` class is defined, `Socket` is not in scope.

Comment: So CoreClass does not get the scope from where I instantiate it (what would be completely logic to me), but from where it was defined? I dont get what sense that makes, i cant copy the whole definition always at the place where I need the Scope - there must be some greater meaning behind this that I just dont get at all?

Comment: I cant even copy the scope like var localCore = CoreClass

Comment: If `CoreClass` is dependent on `Socket`, then alter `CoreClass`'s constructor function to take a socket as a parameter. You might want to do the same for `Localisation`, otherwise `CoreClass` is expecting a bunch of things to be global which will probably bite you later (especially if you unit test).

Comment: Also, think about what could happen if `CoreClass` really could access the `Socket` variable in your case. Wouldn't that be a security concern? In other words, if instead of this, you were instantiating some third party class and that object could access any variable you happened to create, wouldn't that be bad?

Comment: Actually I would need a kind of sandbox were global Objects like Localisation, View and so on are global to the sandbox, but trapped inside it but IIFE only works with var variables and they are not seen by the instanciated objects :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists only in `Request` scope because you define it (`var Socket`) inside that function.

Instead, you define `Localisation` in the outer scope, which can be accessed by the inner scope of `CoreClass`.

Possible fixes:

```
CoreClass = function() {
    console.log('CoreClassLocalisation', Localisation) // works??
    console.log('CoreClassSocket', Socket) // undefined, hell why, its even closer?
}

var Localisation = 'im a localisation'
var Socket

Request = function() {
    Socket = 'im a socket'
    new CoreClass()
}

new Request
```

Another one:

```
CoreClass = function(Socket) {
    console.log('CoreClassLocalisation', Localisation) // works??
    console.log('CoreClassSocket', Socket) // undefined, hell why, its even closer?
}

var Localisation = 'im a localisation'

Request = function() {
    var Socket = 'im a socket'
    new CoreClass(Socket)
}

new Request
```

And even other ways to turn around it